# any way to chain == and || operands

Tags: swift

I have a situation where I have to make a check like this:

```
if foo == a || foo == b || foo == c {
  //do stuff
}
```

is there any way to chain these operands into something smaller like IDK
`foo == a||b||c`

Comment: What about a switch statement? switch foo { case a, b, c: // do something  default: break }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [a, b, c].contains(foo) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I ain't no swift expert but if this creates some sort of container then tests that container contains something, then you've sacrificed performance for the sake of a few characters of typing. Or does some sort of compiler optimise this out?

Comment: @Bathsheba basically you make an array, and search the item in the array, yes it reduces performance