# How do I say “if x == A or B or C” as succinctly in Swift as possible?

Tags: swift

I often encounter the following kind of situation in Swift code:

```
if x == A || x == B {
    // do something
}
```

Is there any way to shorten it?

Comment: whats wrong with that?

Comment: use switch case for alternate

Comment: What could A,B or C be in terms of data types? can help determine if there is a better way

Comment: I just wonder if there's a simpler way. Question is valid for any data type.

Comment: Another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345267/any-way-to-chain-and-operands.

Answer (score 8):

I like switch statements for cases like this

```
switch x {
    case A, B, C:
        // do stuff
    case D:
       // other stuff
    default:
      // do default stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Array instead, if all values of same type. if you just want to check x is matching to any values.

for example:

```
let x = 10
let A = 20
let B = 40
let C = 40


let myArray = [A, B,C]


if myArray.contains(x) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: In terms of search item in collection `Set` will be faster. `Array` would be `O(n)` and `Set` using hashes would be somewhere near `O(log(n))` on average.

Comment: @user28434 For this few elements, the overhead of hashing would be **way** slower than linear search

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, indeed, if author really needs to compare only 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x ^ A) * (x ^ B) * (x ^ C) == 0 {
    //do what you need
}
```

Shorter? Not sure... More impressive? Definitely.

Comment: `|` would be faster than `*`

Comment: Will only work if `x`, `A`, `B`, `C` are conforming to `BitwiseOperations` protocol (if `^` and `|` is used), and for `*` you need extra protocol conformance.  And to compare it with `0` you also need to define `==` with left operand being `x`'s type, and right being `Int`. So that solution only works on really small subset of types, or if `x` is some kind of `Int`, and it may not be.

Comment: Also it does not short-circuit as the `||` operator does.